# Implement Library in Android

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android still in basic step. I am trying to implement WebView in one of my basic application located [here](https://github.com/AzimoLabs/WebViewTester).

There no any details for how to use it. I have checked sample application. I have copied WebViewTester.java as given detail in instruction. I am now trying to use it in my application like below code.

```
public class ShowContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_content);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvSample);

        // Enable javascript
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(WebViewTester());

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
}
```

Now I am getting error in this line

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new TesterWebViewClient());
```

like

```
TesterWebViewClient cannot be resolved to a type
```

What's the issue? Can anybody please correct me? Sorry for basic questions. I am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There no any details for how to use it. I have checked sample application

Really?

sampleapp/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(path: ':webviewtester')
}
```

The README also says how to use it. You add this to your `app/build.gradle`

> #### Download
>
> **Library dependency**
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>   compile 'com.azimolabs.webviewtester:webviewtester:0.1'
> }
> ```

---

**OR** you could have copied it,

> Now I am getting error in this line
>
> ```
> webView.setWebViewClient(new TesterWebViewClient());
> ```

And that makes sense because the class name is actually `WebViewTester`